# How to setup class hierarchy with constructor injected services

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have a few logic classes implemented as services. They do some similar stuff, so I wanted to setup a hierarchy:

```
namespace \Company\Bundle\Service;

abstract class ParentLogic {
    protected $user;
    public function __construct($security_token_storage) {
        $this->user = $security_token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
    }
}

class ChildLogic extends ParentLogic {
}
```

Here is how I have the services setup

```
services:
    parentlogic:
        abstract: true
        class: Company\Bundle\Service\ParentLogic
        arguments: [@security.token_storage]
    childlogic:
        class: Company\Bundle\Service\ChildLogic
        parent: parentlogic
```

however when I try to use the childlogic service in a controller

```
namespace Company\Bundle\Controller;

class TestController {
    static public function getLogicService() {
        return $this->get('childlogic');
    }
}
```

I get an error saying the argument to the constructor is missing:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for Company\Bundle\Service\parentlogic::__construct(), called in /file/path/to/company/app/cache/dev/classes.php on line 2220 and defined

Is this possible? If so what am I doing wrong, or better how is it done correctly?

Comment: Can you show us __construct method of ChildLogic?

Comment: @michaJIS it's intentionally not defined as it would be identical to the parent

Comment: From the docs: "Specifically, the setter methods defined for the parent service will be called when the child services are instantiated." I don't think arguments will be used.  Never tried it.  Always used setter methods.  Try adding a setSecurityTokenStorage method.

Comment: Please be aware that at the moment of initialization of this class, the Token might not be in the Token storage yet. Call getToken() when you need it, not when you initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

What Cerad said in the comment is probably true. Constructor arguments are not used on parent services. We have a similar setup with controllers where we have an AbstractController as a parent service and concrete controllers that inherit from AbstractController. However in our service definition we add any dependencies to the parent using setter-calls:

```
services:
    abstract_controller:
        class: Bundle\Controller\AbstractController
        abstract: true
        calls:
            - [setSomething, ['@something']]
            - [setAnotherThing, ['@anotherThing']]
    concrete_controller:
        class: Bundle\Controller\ConcreteController
        parent: abstract_controller
```

Works like a charm.

I reckon if you wish to use constructor arguments instead you should specify them explicitly in your child service definitions as well since on creation of the child service the parent constructor will be called.